# Play video while hover to highlighted words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a function with video play while mouseover the highlighted words and pause when mouse leave. 
But currently i only know how to auto play while mouseover the video not the highlighted words.
Wish any could help me on this.
Thanks

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><video width="250px" height="250px"  controls preload onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()" >
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    Not Supporting
   </video></a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" >Play&Pause</a>
```

Comment: If you want any questions on how to use jQuery, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can achieve this without jQuery (as you don't appear to be using it in your snippet) is to assign an `id` to the video then add `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to the `a` tag which targets the element with that `id`.

- Add `id="video"` to the `video` tag
- Add `onmouseover="document.getElementById('video').play()"` and `onmouseout="document.getElementById('video').pause()"` to the `a` tag containing the "Play&Pause" text

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <video width="250px" height="250px" controls preload onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()" id="video">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Not Supporting
  </video>
</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('video').play()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('video').pause()">Play&Pause</a>
```

To tidy up your code you can centralise this functionality and remove the inline JavaScript.

- Add `class="trigger"` to elements that will trigger the play and pause events
- In JavaScript loop through the elements with the `trigger` class and attach the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events

```js
var triggers = document.getElementsByClassName('trigger');
var video = document.getElementById("video");

for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  triggers[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    video.play()
  }, false);
  triggers[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
    video.pause()
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <video class="trigger" width="250px" height="250px" controls preload id="video">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Not Supporting
  </video>
</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a class="trigger" href="#">Play&Pause</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is ! https://jsfiddle.net/Alteyss/vsvzh3m2/

Using simple jQuery, simulating the mouse.

```
$("#btn").mouseover(function() {
    $("video").mouseover();
});

$("#btn").mouseout(function() {
    $("video").mouseout();
});
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery alone, and targeting the elements rather than using inline scripting:

```
var $myVideo = $( "#myVideo" ),
    $myBtn   = $( "#play_btn" );

$myBtn.hover(function() {
    $myVideo[0].play();
    }, function() {
    $myVideo[0].pause();
});
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cddqfpd1/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Add a `<span id="text"></span>` around your highlighted Text

```
$( '#text' ).hover(
 function() {
  $( 'video' ).play();
 }, function() {
  $( 'video' ).pause();
 }
);
```